# store multiple button results into dictionary

Tags: javascript

There is a thumb-up button on each message bubble of the chatbot. As there are multiple bubbles on each page, both the text bubble and the thumb-up button are indexed. I am attempting to store the results of all the thumb-up buttons in a dictionary. However, this function only saves the last thumb-up value. I am curious why this is happening.

```
let clickedThumbUP = false;
let rating_dict = { "ratingUp": {}};

//for each click, we store the button id and click response to a dictionary, then we push the entire dictionary to the database? 
let rating_up = $(".thumbup").click(function(){
  
  //let rating_up  = checkRating(clickedThumbUP);
  clickedThumbUP = !clickedThumbUP; // Toggle state on each click

  // get button id
  buttonid = $(this).data("index")

  if (clickedThumbUP === true) {
        $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");

        //store result in dictionary
         rating_dict['ratingUp'][buttonid] = true;
        //user can't press the thumbdown button

          return true
        }
      
      else{

        $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");

        //for (let item of Object.entries(rating_dict['ratingUp'])){
          rating_dict['ratingUp'][buttonid] = false;
        //}

        return false

      
    }
  

  });
```

html

```
<div class="msg ${side}-msg">
  <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${img})"></div>
  <div class="ratings">
    
 
  <div class="msg-bubble">
    <div class="rating-img">
    <button type="submit" class="thumbup" data-index="${message_index}""></button>
    <button type="submit" class="thumbDown" id="thumbDown-${message_index}"></button>
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="msg-text">${text}</div>  
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say it only stores the last thumb-up value, do you meant that it's missing `index`s of the buttons you clicked previously, or the `true`/false` value is incorrect? Might help if you share a snippet of your html code with at least two messages

Comment: it only stores the latest button being clicked. true/false value is correct. I added the html code

Comment: Are you sure whatever generates `${message_index}` is generating unique identifiers?

Comment: I set the number as 12 digits so the likelihood of generating the same number is very low and I was only testing 3 messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want each of your thumbs-up buttons to have its own true/false state, maintaining one global variable `clickedThumbUP` to track if the value is true/false isn't going to do that for you, as clicking on one thumbs-up button and then a different one will change this single global variable value. Instead, check if your thumbs-up button index is already in your `rating_dict` object, and use that to determine if your thumbs-up button is active or not for the message:

```js
const rating_dict = {"ratingUp": {}};

const rating_up = $(".thumbup").click(function() {
  // get button id
  const buttonid = $(this).data("index");
  const isActive = Boolean(rating_dict.ratingUp[buttonId]);
  $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black"); // we toggle this class regardless of which branch we take below, so we can move it up here instead of repeating it twice 
  if (isActive) { // if it's active, make it inactive
    $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");
    rating_dict.ratingUp[buttonid] = false;
    return false
  } else {
    rating_dict.ratingUp[buttonid] = true;
    return true
  }
});
```

This can be refactored further by removing the if-statement, and instead negating the current `buttonid` value and updating the object accordingly. This works because if your button isn't in the object, you'll get `undefined`, which when negated using `!` becomes `true`:

```js
const rating_dict = {"ratingUp": {}};

const rating_up = $(".thumbup").click(function() {
  const buttonid = $(this).data("index");
  $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");

  rating_dict.ratingUp[buttonId] = !rating_dict.ratingUp[buttonId];
  return rating_dict.ratingUp[buttonId];
});
```

---

Notes:

- [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click-shorthand/) is deprecated in jQuery, instead, use `.on("click", function { ... })`
- Using `return true` or `return false` in `.click()` or `.on()` impacts if you prevent the default behavior of what you're clicking on. It also stops the event from "bubbling" up the DOM to the parent elements. You typically want this to be consistent each time you click, so it's a bit strange that you sometimes `return false` and other times `return true`. If you don't need it, remove the `return` in your event handler callback.
- If you're not doing anything with jQuery object that's being stored in the `rating_up` variable you can remove it, and just use `$(".thumup").on("click", ...)` without assigning it to anything.
- Most of your jQuery code can be replaced with vanilla JS:

  - `.click()` can be replaced with `.addEventListener("click", function(e) {...})`. You will need to get your elements using [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then iterate your elements and add the event listener to each, or use [event-delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/5648954) if you use this option.
  - `$(this).data("index")` can be replaced with `this.dataset.index`
  - `$(this).toggleClass(...)` can be replaced with `this.classList.toggle(...)`

Comment: the second answer is really smart!! I'm a long time Python user and I'm pretty new to JS. I found that one of things I'm struggling is there seem to be many ways a click function can be written...

Comment: @Lucia No worries. If you're using jQuery, then `.on("click", ...)` is what you want to use (as `.click()` is deprecated). If you're using plain JS without jQuery, then `.addEventListener("click", ...)` is what you would want to use. But yeah, there are definitely a number of different ways click event handlers can be added so I can see why it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a global `clickedThumbUP` variable to manage the state of all the thumb-up buttons. Instead you need have a place to store the state of each button.

One place to store the state for each button element would be on a [custom data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for each button:

```
let rating_dict = { "ratingUp": {} };
let thumbUpButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbup');
thumbUpButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let buttonid = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-index');
    let clickedThumbUP = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-clicked') === 'true';
    clickedThumbUP = !clickedThumbUP;

    // Update data-clicked attribute with new state
    event.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-clicked', clickedThumbUP);

    if (clickedThumbUP) {
      event.currentTarget.classList.add('thumb-up-black');
      event.currentTarget.classList.remove('thumbup');
    } else {
      event.currentTarget.classList.add('thumbup');
      event.currentTarget.classList.remove('thumb-up-black');
    }
    rating_dict['ratingUp'][buttonid] = clickedThumbUP;
    console.log(rating_dict);
  });
});
```